# NodeJS/Express: Errors using Bliss as the template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express

I'm trying to replace Jade with [Bliss](https://github.com/cstivers78/bliss/wiki) as the template engine for a sample Express web site on NodeJS.  Here's the contents of app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    Bliss = new require('bliss'),
    bliss = new Bliss({ext: '.jhtml'}),
    app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    // app.set('view engine', 'bliss'); /* replaced with app.engine() call below */
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); });

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    app.locals.pretty = true; });

app.get('/', /* routes.index */ function(req, res){
    var index = bliss.compile('index');
    bliss.render(index); });

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port')); });
```

I've tried a few things from other SO issues, but I'm not familiar enough with Node, Express or Bliss to debug why it's returning the following 500 error:

```
500 TypeError: Object function anonymous() { var __out=[],write=__out.push.bind(__out),__tmp=0,render=this.render;write("index"); return __out.join(''); } has no method 'indexOf'
```

I'm fairly confident that the templates and views are set up properly, as they are very simple and follow the Bliss wiki closely.

Is this due to Bliss not being fully compatible with Express?
Is there a better way to set it up to work properly?

Comment: yes, of course I've seen that. It didn't work with the app example I'm using which prompted my question in the first place.

Comment: I'm hoping someone familiar with using Bliss with Express will see this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem

assumes all my bliss files have .js.html extension

## FILES

**app.js**

```
var Bliss = require('bliss');
var bliss = new Bliss();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/bliss');
app.set('view engine', 'js.html');
app.engine('js.html', function(path, options, fn){

   // res.render is calling this
   // update context here (available to all templates)
   var ctx = options.context;
   console.log("context", ctx);
   if (typeof ctx === 'undefined') {
      ctx = {};
   }

   // these will write over what's already in the context
   ctx.name2   = 'MEH2';
   //ctx.name1   = 'MEH1';
   //ctx.layout  = 'layout2';

   var output = bliss.render(path, ctx); 
   fn(null, output); // fn ==> function(error, str) 
});
```

**router file  index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  console.log("ready to render index1.js.html");

  var ctx = {context : {name1 : 'mike1'}};
  ctx.context.layout = 'layout1';

  res.render('index1', ctx);
};
```

**index1.js.html file**

```
@!(ctx)

@function title() {
   WOW @ctx.name1, @ctx.name2
}

@function body() {
<div>
   <h2> Hello @ctx.name1</h2>
</div>
}

@*choose the layout based on the context*@
@render(ctx.layout, body, title, ctx)
```

**layout1.js.html**

```
@!(body, title, ctx)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> @title() </title>
</head>
  <body>
  <h1> REALLY @ctx.title </h1>
  LAYOUT 1
  @body()
  </body>
</html>
```

**layout2.js.html is the same except has LAYOUT 2 as its text**

Now play with app.js/app.engine function to watch how you can affect the context at different stages

**COMMENT:** now that I got express.js and bliss working, I decided to go ahead and use jade. I like bliss' syntax but in addition to spending way too much time getting bliss to work, I decided I wasn't ready to commit fully to it :)